# JQuery Get Height Of Each Div Element

Tags: jquery, height

I have the following function to get the height of each div element with a particular css class. Each container has a side button composed of a div element. I can't set the height of the button div with css because it depends on the height of the container div and each container can be a different height. So I have to do it with jquery. I am trying to set the height of the button based on the height of the container so they are equal heights. Get the container height and set the button height equal to that.

Can you help? Thank you!

```
// sidebar button
function SideBarBtn(){
    $('.ContactWrap').each(function(){
        var FormHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        var SideBtnHeight = FormHeight -25 + 'px';
        $('.SideBtn').css('height', SideBtnHeight);
        $('.SideBtn').fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

html:

```
<div class="ContactWrap">
   <a href="#submit" class="SideBtn"> S u b m i t - B a r</a>
   .....
</div>
```

Comment: @usser1002039 Obviously, the relevant HTML code. Your document structure containing `.ContactWrap` and `.SideBtn` is very important for this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by these lines:

```
$('.SideBtn').css('height', SideBtnHeight);
$('.SideBtn').fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

These selectors select **all** elements with class `SideBtn`, and apply the new styles to it. To solve the problem, you have to use a more specific selector.

The correct code is:

```
var $btn = $(this).find('.SideBtn');
$btn.css('height', SideBtnHeight);
$btn.fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I need to set the button height based on the container height. This seems to set the container height.

Comment: This code is based on the code in your question. Can you show your relevant **HTML** code?

Comment: Thank you!, I just figured it out also... var mcSideBtn = $('.mcSideBtn', this);

Comment: FYI, `$('.mcSideBtn', this)` is short for `$(this).find('.mcSideBtn')`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over elements with the class `.ContactWrap`, but applying the height change and fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeIn, to ALL elements with the class `.SideBtn`. So every time that `.each()` loop iterates, it's calling that `.css()` and the fade functions on EVERY `.SideBtn` element. That's why the height always ends up being the last value you get for `SideBtnHeight`. You actually are getting all the different values, but only the last one sticks.